# Solução para Problema do Banheiro Unisex em Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Suponha que você está em uma festa na república Calamidade Pública que possui apenas um banheiro com n boxes, onde box é um compartimento com um sanitário. A regra da república diz que o banheiro pode ser usado tanto por homens quanto mulheres, mas não ao mesmo tempo. Faça um algoritmo concorrente baseado em monitor que controle o uso deste banheiro.

A entrada no banheiro é realizada pelo procedimento entraBanheiro. Depois de entrar no banheiro com sucesso, as pessoas devem chamar o procedimento escolhaBox, para utilizar um box. Se todos os boxes estiverem em uso então elas devem esperar em uma fila, pois não há espaço suficiente no banheiro. Depois de usar um box, cada pessoa chama o procedimento liberaBox para que os outros possam utilizá-lo.

A república ainda impõe que a utilização do banheiro deve ser justa da seguinte maneira. Suponha que, em um determinado instante, o banheiro está em uso por x pessoas de um mesmo sexo (alguns usando boxes e outros esperando), e a primeira pessoa do sexo oposto chega, chamada P.

Então:

• P somente entra no banheiro após a saída de todos os x indivíduos do banheiro;

• Enquanto P está esperando, se outros indivíduos do mesmo sexo chegam, eles usarão o banheiro simultaneamente com P;

• Enquanto P está à espera, se indivíduos do sexo oposto chegam para usar o banheiro, eles entram no banheiro depois de P (e seus companheiros do mesmo sexo, se for o caso) saírem do banheiro;

• Enquanto P (e companheiros do mesmo sexo) estão usando o banheiro, se pessoas do mesmo sexo de P chegar, eles vão esperar todas as pessoas do sexo oposto de P saírem antes de começar a usar o banheiro.

Cada pessoa de ambos os sexos deve ser um processo separado. Não existe uma pessoa controlando o acesso ao banheiro, mas todas as pessoas sabem das regras de uso do banheiro e as obedecem (ninguém fura a fila!).

Três problemas deverão ser abordados:

Problema 1
Considere que o banheiro tem apenas um box (n = 1).
Ao todo, 50 pessoas irão usar o banheiro, com um gerador de números aleatórios definindo o sexo (com probabilidade igual).
Use um gerador de números aleatórios, de modo que o tempo entre chegada de pessoas seja entre 1 e 7 segundos.
Cada pessoa usa o banheiro durante exatamente 5 segundos.
Use threads e monitores para sincronização. Você também pode usar memória compartilhada.

Ao final da execução do programa deve ser exibido um relatório contendo:

• Quantidade de pessoas de cada sexo;

• Tempo médio de espera para usar o banheiro para cada sexo;

• Taxa de ocupação do box (tempo em uso / tempo total).

Problema 2:
Considere agora que o banheiro tem 3 boxes (n = 3) e que o número total de pessoas é 150.

Problema 3:
Considere agora que o banheiro tem 5 boxes (n = 5) e que o número total de pessoas é 250

```
import threading
import random
from time import sleep

# constants
MALE = 1
FEMALE = 0

print("\n***************************************************************\nBem vindo ao banheiro unisex da Rep. Calamidade Pública\n***************************************************************\n\nDigite 1 para Problema 1\nDigite 2 para Problema 2\nDigite 3 para Problema 3\n\n***************************************************************")
print("")
menu = input("Seleção: ")

# global variables
queue = list()               # to maintain queue outside bathroom
countPerson = 1                  # provides id for each person
countMale = 0
countFemale = 0
PeopleInBathroom = 0
GenderUsingBathroom = 0

if menu == '1':
    numBox = 1
elif menu == '2':
    numBox = 3
elif menu == '3':
    numBox = 5


# semaphores
sem_bathroom = threading.Semaphore(value=numBox)
sem_queue = threading.Semaphore()
sem_mutex = threading.Semaphore()


#generates people who need to use bathroom at random times
def GeneratePeople():
    global queue
    global countMale
    global countFemale
    global countPerson

    if menu == '1':
        sem_queue.acquire()
        for i in range(0, 50):
            if random.randint(0,1) == MALE:
                queue.insert(0,[MALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countMale += 1
                print ("Um homem chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
            else:
                queue.insert(0,[FEMALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countFemale += 1
                print ("Uma mulher chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
        sem_queue.release()
    elif menu == '2':
        sem_queue.acquire()
        for i in range(0, 150):
            if random.randint(0,1) == MALE:
                queue.insert(0,[MALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countMale += 1
                print ("Um homem chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
            else:
                queue.insert(0,[FEMALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countFemale += 1
                print ("Uma mulher chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
        sem_queue.release()
    elif menu == '3':
        sem_queue.acquire()
        for i in range(0, 250):
            if random.randint(0,1) == MALE:
                queue.insert(0,[MALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countMale += 1
                print ("Um homem chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
            else:
                queue.insert(0,[FEMALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countFemale += 1
                print ("Uma mulher chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
        sem_queue.release()
# end of GeneratePeople

# function to send people into bathroom for queue
def entraBanheiro():
    global queue
    global GenderUsingBathroom
    global PeopleInBathroom

    while 1:
        sem_queue.acquire()
        if len(queue)>0:
            p = queue.pop()
            sem_queue.release()
            sem_mutex.acquire()  # for GenderUsingBathroom
            if GenderUsingBathroom == p[0] :    # if same gender, go in
                sem_mutex.release()
                sem_bathroom.acquire()
                t = threading.Thread(target=liberaBox,args=(p,))
                t.start()
            else:                               # if different gender, wait till all others come out
                print ("Esperando por outra pessoa do mesmo sexo")
                while PeopleInBathroom > 0:
                    sem_mutex.release()
                    sleep(1)
                    sem_mutex.acquire()
                sem_mutex.release()
                sem_bathroom.acquire()
                GenderUsingBathroom = p[0]
                t1 = threading.Thread(target=liberaBox,args=(p,))
                t1.start()
        else:
            sem_queue.release()
# end of entraBanheiro


def liberaBox(person):             # monitors the usage of bathroom for each person
    global PeopleInBathroom
    flag = 1
    sem_mutex.acquire()
    if person[0] == FEMALE:
        print("Uma mulher acabou de entrar no banheiro")
        flag = 0
    else:
        print ("Um homem acabou de entrar no banheiro")
    PeopleInBathroom += 1   # enters bathroom
    sem_mutex.release()
    sleep(5)    # spend some time in bathroom
    sem_mutex.acquire()
    PeopleInBathroom -= 1   #leave bathroom
    print ("Pessoa #" , person[1]," acabou de sair do banheiro")
    sem_mutex.release()
    sem_bathroom.release()
# end of liberaBox

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=GeneratePeople)
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=entraBanheiro)
    t2.start()

    #print("\n***************************************************************\nEstatisticas\n\n***************************************************************\n")
    #print("Homens: ", countMale)
    #print("Mulheres: ", countFemale)
```

O grande problema e que ele não esta executando a segunda thread, ele primeiro coloca todo mundo na fila do banheiro depois deixa entrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def GeneratePeople():
    global queue
    global countMale
    global countFemale
    global countPerson

    if menu == '1':
        sem_queue.acquire()
        for i in range(0, 50):
            if random.randint(0,1) == MALE:
                queue.put([MALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countMale += 1
                print ("Um homem chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
            else:
                queue.put([FEMALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countFemale += 1
                print ("Uma mulher chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
        sem_queue.release()
    elif menu == '2':
        sem_queue.acquire()
        for i in range(0, 150):
            if random.randint(0,1) == MALE:
                queue.put([MALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countMale += 1
                print ("Um homem chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
            else:
                queue.put([FEMALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countFemale += 1
                print ("Uma mulher chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
        sem_queue.release()
    elif menu == '3':
        sem_queue.acquire()
        for i in range(0, 250):
            if random.randint(0,1) == MALE:
                queue.put([MALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countMale += 1
                print ("Um homem chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
            else:
                queue.put([FEMALE,countPerson]);
                countPerson += 1
                countFemale += 1
                print ("Uma mulher chegou na fila na posição #", countPerson-1)
                sleep(random.randint(1, 7))
        sem_queue.release()

# end of GeneratePeople

# function to send people into bathroom for queue
def entraBanheiro():
    global queue
    global GenderUsingBathroom
    global PeopleInBathroom

    while 1:
        sem_queue.acquire()
        if queue.qsize() > 0:
            p = queue.get()
            sem_queue.release()
            sem_mutex.acquire()  # for GenderUsingBathroom
            if GenderUsingBathroom == p[0] :    # if same gender, go in
                sem_mutex.release()
                sem_bathroom.acquire()
                t1 = threading.Thread(target=liberaBox,args=(p,))
                t1.start()
            else:                               # if different gender, wait till all others come out
                print ("Esperando por outra pessoa do mesmo sexo")
                while PeopleInBathroom > 0:
                    sem_mutex.release()
                    #sleep(1)
                    sem_mutex.acquire()
                sem_mutex.release()
                sem_bathroom.acquire()
                GenderUsingBathroom = p[0]
                t2 = threading.Thread(target=liberaBox,args=(p,))
                t2.start()
        else:
            sem_queue.release()
# end of entraBanheiro


def liberaBox(person):             # monitors the usage of bathroom for each person
    global PeopleInBathroom
    flag = 1
    sem_mutex.acquire()
    if person[0] == FEMALE:
        print("Uma mulher acabou de entrar no banheiro")
        flag = 0
    else:
        print ("Um homem acabou de entrar no banheiro")
    PeopleInBathroom += 1   # enters bathroom
    sem_mutex.release()
    sleep(5)    # spend some time in bathroom
    sem_mutex.acquire()
    PeopleInBathroom -= 1   #leave bathroom
    print ("Pessoa #" , person[1]," acabou de sair do banheiro")
    sem_mutex.release()
    sem_bathroom.release()
# end of liberaBox

if __name__ == "__main__":

      t3 = Process(target=GeneratePeople).start()
      t4 = Process(target=entraBanheiro).start()
```